# Access Control Jena TDB OWL

Tags: sparql, jena, owl

I use jena TDB to store my ontology, and I want to limit access to users, such as using a tdb file system I do not know if i can contol the access 
thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in access control to a TDB store. This is because access control is closely tied to identity and authorisation (you have to know who a query issuer is and what they are permitted or banned from doing), and this is application specific. It wouldn't make sense for Jena to be prescriptive about how your application handles user identity, for example.

There are approaches that build on top of RDF stores to add a security layer. For example, [this paper from ISWC 2009](http://dig.csail.mit.edu/2009/Papers/ISWC/rdf-access-control/paper.pdf) shows one way to do it, and you can find various others from the [citations of that paper](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=3387545826616712598&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en) or via Google. For more all-round security, you should also ensure that the TDB files and directory have appropriate access restrictions at the OS level, to prevent an attacker from circumventing application-level security by issuing command-line queries.